# How can I configure maven project so that tests are not broken when main code changes?

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I noticed I can run into binary-compatibility problems between main source and test source in maven project configuration. When I change main code, and run  maven `test` target the main code is recompiled, but dependent tests aren't. This may lead to `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`.

Here is simple example:

project structure:

> mavenbug
>   |- src/main/java/App.java
>   |- src/test/java/AppClassTest.java
>   |- pom.xml

App.java:

```
package mavenbug;

public class App {

    public static class BaseData {}

    public static class DerivedData extends BaseData {}

    public void method(BaseData data) {
        System.out.println("hello2 " + data.getClass().toString());
    }
}
```

AppClassTest.java:

```
package mavenbug;

import mavenbug.App.DerivedData;

import org.junit.Test;

public class AppClassTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        new App().method(new DerivedData());
    }

}
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>mavenbug</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>mavenbug</name>
  <description>simplest example of bug</description>
  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
     </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <resources />
    <testResources />
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting />
</project>
```

Ok let's run maven `test`:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building mavenbug 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ mavenbug ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ mavenbug ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to E:\workax4\mavenbug\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ mavenbug ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ mavenbug ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to E:\workax4\mavenbug\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ mavenbug ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: E:\workax4\mavenbug\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running mavenbug.AppClassTest
hello2 class mavenbug.App$DerivedData
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.063 sec

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO]
```

Nice, everything fine. Now change method signature in `App.java` to:

```
public void method(DerivedData data) {
```

This doesn't need any source change in `AppClassTest.java`, as call matches the new argument type.

Let's re-run  maven target `test`:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building mavenbug 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ mavenbug ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ mavenbug ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to E:\workax4\mavenbug\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ mavenbug ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ mavenbug ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ mavenbug ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: E:\workax4\mavenbug\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running mavenbug.AppClassTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.063 sec <<< FAILURE!
test(mavenbug.AppClassTest)  Time elapsed: 0.007 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: mavenbug/App.method(Lmavenbug/App$BaseData;)V
    at mavenbug.AppClassTest.test(AppClassTest.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)


Results :

Tests in error: 
  test(mavenbug.AppClassTest): mavenbug/App.method(Lmavenbug/App$BaseData;)V

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.071 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-02-12T12:50:17+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 38M/64M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project mavenbug: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to E:\workax4\mavenbug\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Opps. Test was looking for method with old param `BaseData` and it didn't found the same binary version.

Can I change pom.xml somehow to avoid this? Or should I always use `clean test` as my target?

Comment: Why are you explicitly configuring the executions within the two plugins, the defaults will do exactly what you want.

Comment: I've uploaded here effective pom.xml that was created for me by eclipse. So maybe my eclipse config is somehow problematic. The same happens for simpler config, see http://pastebin.com/AGDA6Uqc

Comment: Ok, what you are seeing here is the consequences of incremental compilation. I am afraid there is no easy answer to this, other than to use mvn clean test (see this blog for some more info http://blog.ltgt.net/maven-is-broken-by-design/)